VPC SC Error Log Upon creating PUB/SUB Push Subscription with Cloud Function As a Endpoint
We have a VPC SC Perimeter enforced in the GCP env. When trying to create a PUB SUB Subscription in the project the Terraform apply is failing as
Error: Error creating Subscription: googleapi: Error 403: Request is prohibited by organization's policy

Subscription details,
Subscription created in ProjectA with Topic also in ProjectA.
It is a Push Subscription with an Push Endpoint being a Cloud Function which is also in ProjectA.

In Log Explorer, VPC SC Logs are not really direct but below is what coming when trying to create the subscription,
{
  "protoPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
    "status": {
      "code": 7,
      "message": "Request is prohibited by organization's policy. vpcServiceControlsUniqueIdentifier: <id>",
      "details": [
        {
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.PreconditionFailure",
          "violations": [
            {
              "type": "VPC_SERVICE_CONTROLS",
              "description": "<id>"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "authenticationInfo": {},
    "requestMetadata": {
      "callerIp": "<IP>"
    },
    "serviceName": "storage.googleapis.com",
    "methodName": "google.storage.buckets.testIamPermissions",
    "resourceName": "projects/<PROJ_NUMBER>",
    "metadata": {
      "vpcServiceControlsUniqueId": "<ID>",
      "violationReason": "NO_MATCHING_ACCESS_LEVEL",
      "ingressViolations": [
        {
          "servicePerimeter": "accessPolicies/<org_policy_id>/servicePerimeters/<perimeter_name>",
          "targetResource": "projects/<PROJ_NUMBER>"
        }
      ],
      "deviceState": "Unknown",
      "resourceNames": [
        "projects/_/buckets/eu.artifacts.<project_name>.appspot.com"
      ],
      "securityPolicyInfo": {
        "organizationId": "<org_id>",
        "servicePerimeterName": "accessPolicies/<org_policy_id>/servicePerimeters/<perimeter_name>"
      },
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.VpcServiceControlAuditMetadata"
    }
  },
  "insertId": "<id>",
  "resource": {
    "type": "audited_resource",
    "labels": {
      "method": "google.storage.buckets.testIamPermissions",
      "service": "storage.googleapis.com",
      "project_id": "<project_name>"
    }
  },
  "severity": "ERROR",
}

The logs doesn't have any Authentication Info ( which can be added within Ingress Rules ) neither anything particular to get to the root cause.
Any resolution for this ?

Found similar question with the same error. It is possibly mismatch on project's name or id, Can you try troubleshooting it with these info:


Check that you're using the correct account

Check that you're using the right project

Check that you've assigned IAM roles properly

make sure the account linked to your environment variable GOOGLE\_APPLICATION\_CREDENTIALS has the correct IAM permission set



